# Let pam module use hostname -s

Tags: rhel, security, pam, active-directory

Our `hostname` command gives back the servername.domain. 
This is in conflict with our authentication mechanism with our Active Directory. 
Is it possible to let the pam module use `hostname -s`  (the short name?)

Comment: I think you need to update your question with more information. Can you explain what you're using to authenticate to AD? Winbind? pam_ldap with win2008r2? pam_krb? Centrify? There's a lot of different ways to skin this particular cat. Also, what issue is it causing? Are you using winbind and it's creating a computer account with an improperly formatted name?

Answer (score 0):

It is depends how you have it setup. If you just use NIS for the NSS layer and pam_krb5 in the PAM configs /etc/pam.d/system-auth and /etc/pam.d/password-auth, there will be no need for you to register your server with AD.